# Disable Support for Reading (Invalid JSON) Single Quote Strings

Tags: c#, json.net

Newtonsoft.Json for C# supports reading stuff like `{'key':'value'}` but thats improper JSON. Is it possible to disable that so it parses and reads more like PHP (Where'as PHP doesnt support {'key':'value'} but {"key":"value"})

Comment: With software design you really want to be as flexible as possible with your inputs and rigorous in your outputs.  So, what's the purpose of constraining the input in this manner?

Comment: @SamAxe: I strongly disagree with that philosophy. I'm very much in favour of only supporting valid inputs. It's the "let's be lax" attitude that leads to so much broken HTML etc. Most XML parsers are pretty strict.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I suppose there's an argument to be made either way.. and like most things what is acceptable will depend on a number of factors.  I very much respect your point of view on this.

Comment: See [Support "strict mode" for RFC7159 parsing #646](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646) where James Newton-King has several suggestions for implementing strict JSON checking including, *What you could do is inherit from JsonTextReader, override `Read` and check the incoming data after each `base.Read()`. If QuoteChar is `'` then throw an error,...*  However the issue got closed with no plans to implement yet.

Comment: @dbc: Funny - I just linked to that issue within my own answer, too :)

Comment: @JonSkeet - well you did open it after all :)

Answer (score 13):

You could write your own `JsonReader` subclass to perform this, but the `JsonTextReader` class (which is the most commonly used one, as far as I'm aware) doesn't support this. From the [`ParseValue`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/a54b0fe4dd367d084d3fbfed3698692515ebf3dd/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonTextReader.cs#L1650) method, for example:

```
case '"':
case '\'':
    ParseString(currentChar, ReadType.Read);
    return true;
```

I have a [strict JSON tokenizer](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf/JsonTokenizer.cs) in Google.Protobuf - it's internal, but should give you some idea that it's not terribly tricky to write such a tokenizer yourself. That doesn't help you if you really want to use Json.NET other than the strictness, of course.

You might want to read and potentially vote/comment on [issue 646](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/646) in the Json.NET repo, where I requested a "strict mode" as well. (There's a suggested alternative approach there, too - although it feels like a bit of a hack.)

Comment: How exactly can I do this? I use JToken.Parse() to read the JSON strings, not entirely sure what im meant to do here.

Comment: @user8549339: And this is why it's always useful to provide a [mcve] - we'd have known which API you were using. It sounds like you want `JToken.Load`, passing in the appropriate reader.

Comment: Im literally using Newtonsoft.Json, just the regular old thing and then use JToken.Parse(string json)

Comment: @user8549339: But calling `JToken.Parse` is only *one* way of using Json.NET - and your question didn't explain what you've told us now. However, I've now explained what you'd do if you wanted to follow the advice in issue 646: you'd create the subclass of `JsonTextReader`, then pass it to `JToken.Load`. But as I say, it's a bit of a hack IMO.